# jQuery validate fails to in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery-validate

I have the following validation code...

```
jQuery('#MyForm').validate({
    ignore: ".ignore",
    rules: {
        FirstName: {
            required: function () { //this works
                return (document.getElementById("FirstName").value === '');
            }
        },
        LastName: {
            required: true //this doesn't work
        }
...
```

For some reason, if I specify the rules like "LastName" above, it doesn't work. However if I put a function to explicitly validate the field, like "FirstName", it does work.

Can anyone suggest a possible reason for this?

Either style works fine in other browsers.

Some other questions have suggested adding "X-UA-Compatible" meta tag, but that makes no difference in this case.

After some further investigation, I can see that it's erroring in jquery.validate.js, at this line...

```
settings[ eventType ].call( validator, this, event );
```

in this block of code...

```
var validator = $.data( this.form, "validator" ),
    eventType = "on" + event.type.replace( /^validate/, "" ),
    settings = validator.settings;
if ( settings[ eventType ] && !$( this ).is( settings.ignore ) ) {
    settings[ eventType ].call( validator, this, event );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be an issue with jQuery Validate v1.18.0, I've downgraded to 1.17.0, and it's working correctly again.